# Converting an ASCII number to a Hex number in C without using library functions

Tags: c, ascii, hex

I want to convert an 32-bit ASCII number (e.g. "FE257469") to the equivalent 32-bit hex number which will be stored on a 32-bit variable. Most importnatly, I want to do that **without** using any library function like sscanf(), atoi(), etc.

Any ideas on that?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Is this homework or why do you want to do it without using a library function?

Comment: How is **FE257469** a 32-bit number? If each character is ASCII, then each character would be 7/8 bits..

Comment: @Colin `FE257469` is `4263867497` decimal.

Comment: :) No guys, it's not. I know that it sounds fairly simple but I just wondered if there is an easy way of doing this (I can't really think clearly at the moment after so many hours of studying!)

Comment: @Colin strictly speaking is not a 32-bit number but it **represents** a 32-bit number, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of such a function based on a switch:

```
unsigned int parseHex( char *str )
{
    unsigned int value = 0;

    for(;; ++str ) switch( *str )
    {
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            value = value << 4 | *str & 0xf;
            break;
        case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
        case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':
            value = value << 4 | 9 + *str & 0xf;
            break;
        default:
            return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is something like:

initialize result to 0

1. convert one digit of input to decimal to get current digit
2. multiply result by 16
3. add current digit to result
4. repeat steps 1-3 for remaining digits